# How to delete rows in MySQL with specific text

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-delete

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTldt.png)

Hello! I'm trying to delete some rows within my file where the State_Name is United States and District of Columbia.

The database names I put as zzz_schema > Tables > 2017_annual

I've tried the delete from command but unfortunately with no luck. my code reads as below:

```
SELECT *
FROM zzz_schema.2017_annual
WHERE Measure_Name = 'Food Insecurity'
DELETE FROM 2017_annual WHERE State_Name = 'United States'
```

The first three lines gives me the correct table (attached as the picture) but I'm having trouble with deleting that specific stuff.

Thank you.

Comment: You should rephrase your question by showing input and expected output.

Comment: Could be a problem with the data, maybe there's some spaces or other whitespace in the `State_Name` column?  Are there rows returned from this query: `SELECT * FROM 2017_annual WHERE State_Name = 'United States'`?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```sql
DELETE
FROM zzz_schema.2017_annual
WHERE Measure_Name = 'Food Insecurity' AND
      State_Name IN ('District of Columbia', 'United States');
```

Comment: Unfortunately that gives me error again. I'm mainly trying to just remove all the rows where District of Columbia and United States are included, but unsure how to input the delete code in its entirety.

Comment: I see no reason why my answer should be producing an _error_ ... as to the correctness of the logic, that is another story.

Comment: I honestly agree, your code looks spot on to me. I am thinking there may be some privilege issue with the user or something by chance. If you happen to know how to edit those permissions by chance? If not I will continue to trouble shoot *fingers crossed*

Comment: Well yes, if you don't have DML permissions on `2017_annual`, then no delete query may work for you.  I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will work-

```
DELETE FROM zzz_schema.2017_annual
WHERE State_Name IN ("United States","District of Colombia");
```

Comment: while this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.